# How do I find out how the python3 package for Ubuntu is built?

Tags: apt, package-management, python

I have noticed that on some tests, the python3 interpreter that I installed with apt-get is faster than if I take the interpreter from python docker containers or build myself.

How do I find out which build options are used to build the interpreter for Ubuntu/Debian repositories?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source & looking; it's all in there.  `apt source python3`